# How do you send a Left-mouse button HOLD + DRAG in VB 2010?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi

I'd like to create a function in my application in Visual basic 2010 that would:

- Simulate a left-mouse button click+hold and drag with a timer tick event
- Set a new XY coordinates for the mouse to drag the item to a new location
- Remove the left-mouse button click+hold command

How do I go about for this function?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "Simulate" and "Remove the left-mouse button click+hold command"? Are these automated (with no user interaction) operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
If Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Button2_MouseDown(New Button, New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y, 0))
    End If


    If Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X <> Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)).X Then

        If Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X > Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)).X Then

            Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - 1, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y)

        ElseIf Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X < Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)).X Then


            Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X + 1, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y)


        End If

    End If

    If Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y <> Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)).Y Then

        If Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y > Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)).Y Then

            Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - 1)

        ElseIf Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y < Button2.PointToScreen(New Point(Button2.Width / 2, Button2.Height / 2)).Y Then


            Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y + 1)


        End If

    End If
```

It's a little bit long to post here so I've created a simple project.

Sample Program [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?z6ydjizzmjmtztj)

Full Source [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?vsn6jbgevowb71g)